# how to update parent object field when we make any changes in child object field?

Tags: apex, trigger

i have a parent object 'salesforce project' and child object 'salesforce ticket' whenever i will select the priority of child object 'high'( then it should update the description field of parent object. how it can be achieved through triggers

```
    List<Salesforce_Project__c> spList = new List<Salesforce_Project__c>();
    List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>();

    for (Salesforce_Ticket__c stObj : Trigger.new) {
        listIds.add(stObj.Salesforce_Project__c);
    }

    spList = [SELECT id,Description__c,(SELECT id, Priority__c FROM Salesforce_Ticket__r) FROM Salesforce_Project__c WHERE id IN :listIds];

    for (Salesforce_Project__c sp : spList)
    {
        for (salesforce_Ticket__c st : Salesforce_Project__c.Salesforce_Ticket__r){
            if(st.Priority__c == 'High')
            {
                sp.Description__c = 'new description through trigger';

            }
            update spList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] your post to describe the specific issue you're struggling with in this code.

Comment: Do not destroy your questions by removing content. I've rolled back these changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Salesforce_Project__c> spList = new List<Salesforce_Project__c>(); // to store the parent records which needs to be updated..
List<Id> listIds = new List<Id>(); //ids of Parent records

//capture the parent record ids into a list
for (Salesforce_Ticket__c stObj : Trigger.new) {
    listIds.add(stObj.Salesforce_Project__c);
}

//fetch all related parent records...
Map<Id, Salesforce_Project__c> salesforceProjectsMap = new Map<Id, Salesforce_Project__c>([SELECT id,Description__c
                                                                        FROM Salesforce_Project__c WHERE id IN :listIds]);


//process all child records and update its related parent record accordingly..
for (Salesforce_Ticket__c stObj : Trigger.new) {
    //your criteria when to update & along with that check if child has parent record or not..
    if(stObj.Priority__c == 'High' && stObj.Salesforce_Project__c != null){
        // to avoid nullpointer exceptions..
        if(salesforceProjectsMap != null && salesforceProjectsMap.containsKey(stObj.Salesforce_Project__c)){
            Salesforce_Project__c temp = salesforceProjectsMap.get(stObj.Salesforce_Project__c);
            temp.Description__c = 'new description through trigger';
            spList.add(temp);
        }
    }
}

if(spList != null && !spList.isEmpty()){
    update spList;
}
```

*See updated code with self explanatory comments.*

**Few points to remember:**

1. Never ever put any query inside Loops. Refer [Salesforce best
   practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)
2. Always maintain list of records which needs to be updated in a separate list rather than directly updating in the original(SOQL result stored list.)

.

Comment: This is a helpful revision, but you don't need to check `salesforceProjectsMap` for `null`; it will never be `null`. Same for `spList`. It can never be `null`, and doing DML on an empty list is a no-op, so the final `if` can be removed.

Comment: I agree on your comment. Thanks @DavidReed

Comment: thanks @DasariPrashanth

Answer (score 1):

Off the bat you want to avoid using a DML statement (the update) in a for loop; keeping it in the loop will cause you to run into governor limits. To avoid this, before you iterate the 'spList' you should initialize an empty list of type Salesforce_Project__c, this list will be all the Salesforce Projects you are updating. Add the new SPs to this list while iterating your Salesforce_Tickets (in your inner for loop) after changing the description value. Then, OUTSIDE both for loops, you can perform the DML statement on the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

Although this can be achieved using Apex Triggers, this functionality can be accomplished via a declarative tool such as a Process Builder or a Workflow Rule.

In order to do so, write a Process Builder or Workflow Rule that executes when a new `Salesforce_Ticket__c` record is created or updated. The criteria for execution would be as follows

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(Priority__c),
    TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Priority__c)) != TEXT(Priority__c),
    TEXT(Priority__c) = 'High'
)
```

Add an action for `Field Update` where you can update the respective parent `Salesforce_Project__c` `Description` field value to ***'Your description text'***.

Using clicks over code is the recommended approach to build custom solutions within Salesforce since declarative solutions are maintainable and do not require the overhead of writing additional unit tests in Apex.

Comment: Declarative solutions do not require test code, but that doesn't mean you can't or shouldn't write integration test code for declarative solutions.

Comment: Agreed John. The idea was to list down the trade offs of selecting a declarative versus a programmatic solution approach.